# ICC can't open header file

Tags: compiler-errors, header-files, icc

I am trying to compile a code (not mine; uses C to communicate with cuda) that came with its own makefile, and I'm getting the following error message:

```
icc  -fPIC  -vec-report1 -g  -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -I. -I/include -DUNIX -DCPU_RECOMPUTE=1 -DFULL_DOUBLE=0 -c classify_functions.cpp -o classify_functions.o

classify_functions.cpp(4): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "cuda_runtime.h"
  #include <cuda_runtime.h>
                           ^

compilation aborted for classify_functions.cpp (code 4)

make: *** [classify_functions.o] Error 4
```

I used "locate" and checked that /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h exists; then I tried adding it to my .bashrc in the variables PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and C_INCLUDE_PATH but none seems to work. Is there another variable for the path of icc header files? If not, why can't the compiler open the file?

(I can provide more info, but I really don't know what is relevant in this case)

Comment: Try adding option `-I/usr/local/cuda/include`

Comment: I assumed you meant in the makefile, so I searched there and found this line: "INCLUDES  += -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include". I couldn't find the definition of that variable anywhere, so I just added "CUDA_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda" and now the problem seems solved, so thanks! (the program returned a different error this time, but it did found the header). Still, I find the need to ADD a variable def in the makefile a little odd; isn't there a way to introduce this in the bashrc?

Comment: As a hack you can add to bashrc: `alias icc='icc -I/usr/local/cuda/include'` and then reload your bash with new settings. Probably there is some variable which should be set. For gcc it is `C_INCLUDE_PATH`. I don't know what is for icc.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux (and probably MacOS), the compiler include path is*

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/compiler/include
```

and the library path is

```
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.128/linux/compiler/lib
```

so you just need to make sure that `cuda_runtime.h` file (along with other necessary header files) are in the compiler path.

*assuming Intel's compiler icc is installed properly, and the installation path is left as default.